# Excel macro for saving embedded Word documents to PDF

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am using current macro for saving Word documents from my Excel workbook to the same folder. Is there any way to convert them to PDF while saving? So instead of saving to Word my Macro would convert them to PDF? I have managed to create Macro for Word for saving to PDF but I cant implement it to work from Excel.

```
    Sub MMmachine()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("MAIN")
    'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
    If ws.Range("B1").Value = True Then
        MYMACRO
    End If
End Sub

Sub MYMACRO()
Const wdFormatDocument = 0
Dim sh As Shape
Dim objWord As Object ''Word.Document
Dim objOLE As OLEObject
Dim wSystem As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next

Set wSystem = Worksheets("MAIN")
''The shape holding the object from 'Create from file'
''Object 2 is the name of the shape
Set sh = wSystem.Shapes("Object 6")
''Activate the contents of the object
sh.OLEFormat.Activate
''The OLE Object contained
Set objOLE = sh.OLEFormat.Object
''This is the bit that took time
Set objWord = objOLE.Object
objWord.Application.Visible = False
''Easy enough
    objWord.SaveAs2 Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyFile.docx", FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatDocumentDefault
objWord.Application.Quit
sh.OLEFormat.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that requires is a trivial code change:

```
objWord.SaveAs2 Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyFile.pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
```

or:

```
objWord.SaveAs2 ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MyFile.pdf", 17
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I have tried it yet before and it saves my document as PDF file however I can't open it. Code you have mentioned just changes file type from DOCX to PDF but it does not print DOCX to PDF. If you change file type manually back to DOCX it works again but I need to print my DOCX to PDF somehow on the go. Thank you in advice!

Comment: Are you using Option Explicit at the top of your code? Have you actually set a reference to Word via Tools|References? Your code's use of 'Dim objWord As Object', for example, implies the use of late binding, but the use of Word constants like wdFormatDocumentDefault implies that you have set the Word reference, which is normally only done with early binding. In other words, your code is inconsistent. See alternate save code in my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying every single way but none of them worked. You saved my project! THANK YOU!

Comment: Can you please point me on solution with "Microsoft Word has stopped working", "Windows can try to recover your information"? While running my macro for second time without closing my Excel document I am getting this error. If I close my Excel workbook with this macro, open it again and run my macro, everything works fine. If I push run button again, I am getting this error.

Comment: You really should start a new question for that - and probably not on StackOverflow. Try repairing the Office installation (via Windows Control Panel > Programs > Programs & Features > Microsoft Office (version) > Change > Repair).

Comment: I have noticed if I delete `objWord.Application.Quit` from the end of code Microsoft Word is not giving any error message. Is there anything wrong with this command? It is working but leading to an error message.

Comment: I suspect that line should either be preceded by a line with 'objWord.ActiveDocument.Close False' or written as 'objWord.Application.Quit False'